# C# Determine which condition was satisfied

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

In my C# code I'm having the following code:

```
if (A == null)
{
    errors.Add(nameof(A), "A does not exist.");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
else if (B == null)
{
    errors.Add(nameof(B), "B does not exist.");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

where types `A` and `B` are treated identically. I am therefore experimenting if these conditions can be merged to obtain more concise code!

Would it be possible to write something like

```
if (A == null || B == null)
{
    errors.Add(nameof(A/B), "A/B does not exist."); // When A == null, use A. When B == null, use B.
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

where we can retrieve information about *which type is null*? In other words, can we find out which of the conditions in the if-statement was satisfied?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to check - you still want that if `A` is `null` we get no information about whether `B` was null or not?

Comment: yes, if both `A` and `B` are null we should be notified about `A`. This can be generalized to more types where `A` > `B` > `C` in priority of notifying about nulls

Comment: @CasperDijkstra what if both are null? What's wrong with the current code (once you move `return Task.CompletedTask;` after the checks) ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ternary` operator.

```
if (A == null || B == null)
{
    errors.Add(nameof(A == null ? A : B), $"{A == null ? "A" : "B"} does not exist."); // When A == null, use A. When B == null, use B.
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: What if both are null? (also applies to the original solution)

Comment: @MichaelGehling, in the original solution when both are null just the  if is executed and not `else if` branch.